# Ruby the hard way ex39 .hash function with % operator

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and learning it using Learn Ruby the Hard Way online book. I am not very clear in Ex39 : http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Confusion code :

```
def Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
# Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to
# an index for the aDict's buckets.

#takes the key arguments and converts it into a hash number 
# that is divided by the length
#of the Dict. The remainder a number on the aDict.
return key.hash % aDict.length
end
```

What is % operator being used for. If key.has creates a unique number why we need to divide it by the length of the Dict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The % operator is the modulo operator. (As in most other current languages)
With it you can make sure, that the final number will never be larger than the value you did divide by.